# How to pickle a lot of subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle

Is it possible to pickle figure with 18*18 subplots?

```
figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.subplots(18, 18, sharex='all', sharey='all', gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([])
with open('fig.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(figure, file)
```

When I try to do it like this I get an error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by increasing your system recursion limit through the `sys` module. The recursion limit is there to put an early stop to any unoptimized/buggy recursion and can be safely increased to ~10,000 for this use case (provided you have the RAM to handle it).

Here's a working example:

```
import pickle 
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


sys.setrecursionlimit(10_000) #this makes it work


figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.subplots(18, 18, sharex='all', sharey='all', gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([])

with open('fig.pickle', 'wb+') as outfile:
    pickle.dump(figure, outfile)
```